# Commutator of momentum and velocity operator in relativistic quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-equation

I am currently reading up on Dirac's 'The Principles of Quantum Mechanics'. 
It is stated there, that for the motion of a free particle with Hamiltonian \begin{equation}H=c(\boldsymbol{\alpha},\boldsymbol{p}+\rho_3 mc^2)\end{equation}
we see at once that the momentum commutes with $H$ and is thus a constant of the motion. Further, the $x_1$-component of the velocity is \begin{equation} \dot{x}_1=[x_1,H]=c\alpha_1. \end{equation} and therefore we see a different relation between velocity and momentum in relativistic quantum mechanics, that they don't commute.

I was able to calculate the commutators $[p_1,H]$ and $[x_1,H]$. But even though I thought intuitively it should be clear, that $[\alpha_1,p_1]\neq0$, when I try to calculate it explicitly, I stumble. The $\alpha_1$-matrix written out should be \begin{equation} \alpha_1=c \left(
        \begin{array}{cccc}
            0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
            0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
            1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
        \end{array} \right)
\end{equation} with eigenvalues $\pm c$.
But now when I calculate 
\begin{equation}
\alpha_1 p_1 u^1=\left(
        \begin{array}{cccc}
            0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
            0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
            1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
        \end{array} \right) \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
  p_1\\
  0\\
  p_1 a\\
  p_1 b
 \end{array}
 \right)= \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
  p_1 b\\
  p_1 a\\
  0\\
  p_1
 \end{array}
 \right)
\end{equation}
i get the same as
\begin{equation}
p_1\alpha_1  u^1=p_1\left(
        \begin{array}{cccc}
            0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
            0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
            1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
        \end{array} \right)\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
  1\\
  0\\
  a\\
  b
 \end{array}
 \right)=p_1\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
  b\\
  a\\
    0\\
  1
 \end{array}
 \right)
\end{equation}
I feel like I'm overseeing something really basic here.

Answer (score 2):

> But even though I thought intuitively it should be clear, that $[\alpha_1,p_1]\neq 0$ [...]

Why do you think this?  $p_1$ is a differential operator, and $\alpha_1$ is a constant matrix.

---

Velocity in the sense of $\dot x = i[H,x]$ is not something which can be measured at any moment in time - it requires two successive position measurements.  One can find a simultaneous eigenbasis of $\alpha_1$ and $\mathbf p$ by simply writing the Dirac spinor components as spatial plane waves

$$\psi = \pmatrix{a(t)\\b(t)\\c(t)\\d(t)} e^{i\mathbf p \cdot \mathbf x}$$
and then choosing an eigenbasis of $\alpha_1$, so $a(t) = \pm d(t)$, and  $b(t) = \pm c(t)$.  Such a basis might be

$$ c_1(t)e^{i\mathbf p \cdot \mathbf x} \pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\1}, \ c_2(t)e^{i\mathbf p \cdot \mathbf x} \pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\-1}, \ c_3(t)e^{i\mathbf p \cdot \mathbf x} \pmatrix{0\\1\\1\\0}, \ c_4(t)e^{i\mathbf p \cdot \mathbf x} \pmatrix{0\\1\\-1\\0}$$

One **cannot**, however, impose the additional demand of harmonic time depenence, because $\alpha_1$ does not commute with the Hamiltonian. Operationally, at the next instant $\alpha_1$ will be different, which means that this basis will no longer be an eigenbasis of it.

Comment: I thought, in relativistic QM, that should be the case even for a free electron, which was stated in the book as well. Velocity and momentum are not precisely measurable at the same time, so their components shouldn't commute and they shouldn't have the same eigentstates, right?

Comment: @EddyPi I deleted the (incorrect) second part of my answer (I blame a lack of sleep for that one), and elaborated on the rest.